# Replace Vowels in a String with their index in the String Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, loops

I need to replace each vowel in a string with its index + 1 within the string.
(Function name = vowel2index)
Output Example:

```
 vowel2index('this is my string') == 'th3s 6s my str15ng'
```

I hope this example shows what I'm trying to do.  I have tried using the replace method as follows:

```
  str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, str.indexOf(/[aeiou]/gi);
```

but that didn't come close to solving the problem. I also tried the code below, but I couldn't figure out where to go from the IF statement (I didn't use array vowels yet):

```
 function vowel2index(str) {
 let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
 let arr = [];
 for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
     if (str[i] === /[aeiou]/gi) {
        arr.push(str.replace(str[i], indexOf(str[i])+1));
     }
```

Any help appreciated. As an FYI, this problem is from codewars.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. The `.replace` function [accepts an `offset` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) that contains the index of the current match, so you can just use the replacer function, and return that offset plus one. No need for an array of vowels, just use the character set of vowels in the pattern:

```js
function vowel2index(str) {
  return str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, (vowel, offset) => offset + 1);
}
console.log(vowel2index('this is my string')); // == 'th3s 6s my str15ng');
```

Comment: (Duplicate comment): Thanks! I'm still not clear on what the offset is. I read the definition of offset from MDN web docs: "The offset of the matched substring within the whole string being examined. (For example, if the whole string was 'abcd', and the matched substring was 'bc', then this argument will be 1.)" Would you mind clarifying this? Thanks again.

Comment: The start of the "bc" substring there is at index 1 in the input string, so `offset` is `1` in that case. (a match at the very beginning of the string would have index 0)

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that your issue is resolved :)

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - click the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere near as clean as @CertainPerformance answer above but a brute-force solution is:

```
function vowel2index(string) {

  var result = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    var c = string.charAt(i);
    if(c.match(/[aeiou]/gi)) {
      result.push(i + 1);
    } else {
      result.push(c);
    }
  }
  return result.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this mate.**

```js
const vowel2index = str => str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, (_, offset) => offset+1) 


console.log(vowel2index('this is my string'))
```

P.S. : It will clear all test cases because i have already solved that kata. (Nice to see someone from codewars ♡)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not clear on what the offset is. I read the definition of offset from MDN web docs: "The offset of the matched substring within the whole string being examined. (For example, if the whole string was 'abcd', and the matched substring was 'bc', then this argument will be 1.)" Would you mind clarifying this? Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah! so the the offset will return the index of starting of substring match so here we are matching only one character so will get the index of that character only (which is 0 based so we add 1 into it as per required in question).

Comment: Thanks! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function vowel2index(str) {
 for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
     if (str[i] === /[aeiou]/gi) {
        str.replace(str[i], indexOf(str[i])+1);
     }
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.